# Не могу получить доступ к iframe

Tags: javascript, form, iframe

Есть форма

```
<form id="s-plugin-cml1c-import" method="post" action="?plugin=cml1c&action=upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="s-plugin-cml1c-import-iframe"><input type="file" name="files"></form>
```

и есть фрейм, куда загружается результат обработки формы

```
<iframe  name="s-plugin-cml1c-import-iframe" id="s-plugin-cml1c-import-iframe"></iframe>
```

В своем js пытаюсь получить данные из формы,загруженные в `iframe`

```
$('#s-plugin-cml1c-import-iframe').load(function (e) {
                try {
                    console.log($(this).contents());
                } catch(e) {...}
```

После вызова `$(this).contents()` выдает ошибку:

> Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from
>   'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://baby-upgrade.ru" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Все происходит в рамках одного домена. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь описана очень похожая проблема:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Рекомендуют использовать Window.postMessage()
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Экспресс-описание можно найти тут https://learn.javascript.ru/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage.

Пример использования

> Проще говоря, если мы хотим отправить сообщение в окно win, то нужно
>   вызвать win.postMessage(data, targetOrigin).

Comment: В этих решениях передают данные из основного окна во фрейм. А мне нужно получить данные из фрейма в основное окно. Так что вариант с postMessage не подходит.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Хорошо, договорились